# Matlab to HTML5 WebSocket

Tags: javascript, html, matlab, websocket, arduino

I need to talk to a matlab script via web sockets from a web page. In my opinion this the best approach as I will not have to pool for http ajax requests. Matlab is controlling an arduino board so real time data is involved.

> Is this possible?
>   The only thing close enough I could find is 
>   [Web-Matlab_Bridge](https://github.com/BrendanAndrade/web-matlab-bridge)

Comment: I doubt there is a ready-made solution in MATLAB to act as a WebSocket server, perhaps you can find some Java library to do it for you? you could always implement it yourself, after all WebSocket is an [open standard](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455).

Comment: Another possibility is to deploy your MATLAB code (using MATLAB Compiler) into a language more suitable for this task (C# or Java), those have better support for web development of this kind..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 easy possibilities (as far as i know):

1)Use a C DLL implementation (e.g. http://libwebsockets.org/).
In Matlab functions of the DLL can be easily accessed: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/using-c-shared-library-functions-in-matlab-.html

2) Use the mex compiler (http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/mex.html) to implement matlab functions using C/C++ code.